# $scope Form Directiva angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tendo dificuldade em criar um directiva no seguinte ponto.

Tenho uma listagem de dados, e nesta listagem tenho um controller callController, e nesta pagina de listagem tenho uma modal que chama um template feito com a diretiva:

```
angular.module('app.directives')
.directive('formCall', function(appAngularConfig) {

    return {
        templateUrl: appAngularConfig.baseUrl + "/build/js/views/templates/__form_call.html",
        restrict: "E"
    }

});
```

Tenho um outro controller que chama editController la tem uma função responsável por chamar a modal e popular os inputs que estão na modal vindo via template pela diretiva, só que não funciona percebo que o editController não "enxerga" o ng-model do template. Agora se eu colocar no mesmo controller onde a modal esta ou seja o callController funciona normalmente.

Olha a diretiva:

```
angular.module('app.directives')
.directive('formCall', function(appAngularConfig) {

    return {
        templateUrl: appAngularConfig.baseUrl + "/build/js/views/templates/__form_call.html",
        restrict: "E",
    }

});
```

Ja de scope como false e nada.

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer a comunicação entre eles determinando o valor em um `factory` e fazendo essa referência ali. Ou então, no primeiro controller você pode definir o seu $scope como $rootScope. Já tentou algo assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer a comunicação dos valores usando o `controller`, que me parece ser o seu caso, você pode definir o valor a ser passado ao modal através de um `$rootScope`, que seria uma "variável" global. Recomendo que tenha cuidado com o uso do $rootScope, pois se houver abuso, você pode acabar tendo problemas futuros com o uso desse scope.

Para usar ele, basta inicializar no controller e depois definir o valor ao $rootScope. Nos módulos seguintes, você não precisa mais fazer a referencia como $rootScope, apenas como $scope, já que ele já foi definido. No seu caso, ficaria algo assim:

```
.controller('callController', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.modalData = [item];
});

.controller('editController', function($scope) {
    var minhaData = $scope.modalData;
    $scope.modal = $scope.modalData;
    //e por ai vai.. 
});
```

Ou você pode referenciar através de um factory, por exemplo:

```
.factory('factPrincipal', function ($http){
    var _modal = false;

    var getData = function() {
        return $http.get('dist/data.json');
    };

    return {
        getData: getData()
    };
}])
```

E no controller:

```
.controller('callController', function($scope, factPrincipal) {
    $scope.modalData = factPrincipal.getData();
});

.controller('editController', function($scope, factPrincipal) {
    $scope.modal = factPrincipal.getData();
});
```

Seria essa sua dúvida?

### Editado

Vi a resposta do Mayllon Baumer só depois, estava elaborando a minha. Mas eu tive o mesmo problema uma vez e a solução do Mayllon não funcionou no meu caso pois o modal era um módulo externo, e os dados não estavam sendo passados, não importa o que eu fizesse. Mas pode ser que para você funcione.

Comment: Celsom, realmente usando o $rootScope funciona, mas não queria utiliza - lo pelo medo de perder o controle por ser uma variavel global. O que eu percebo como o formulario é uma diretiva com template o ng-model deste formulario não é enxergado em outro controller. Somente no controller que chama a pagina onde a modal se encontra.

Comment: Você mesmo criou o modal ou é algum open source? Já tentou a solução do Mayllon?

Comment: Ps.: No meu caso, quando eu realmente preciso de um $rootScope, eu sempre faço a declaração com o prefixo `_` ex.: `$rootScope._algumaCoisa` assim eu sei que se existir um `$scope._algumaCoisa`, na verdade é uma referência à uma variável global. Se não houver outra saída, é uma questão de montar um fluxo bom para você. Comigo funcionou assim.

Comment: Hummm, boa dica. Vou usar dessa forma que vc disse então.

Comment: Não há jeito de transferir ou mesclar os dois controllers? Qual o objetivo de você possuir 2 controllers que vão interagir com o mesmo modal?

Comment: Na verdade queria separa este controller. 
Tenho um controller que lista os dados onde a modal esta, e queria outro controller onde os dados serão atualizados.
No controller onde a modal esta tem uma tabela onde tenho um ng-click:
<a href="" ng-click="openModalEditCall(call)"> <img src="/build/icons/page_edit.png"> </a>

E no outro controller, que gostaria de ter receberia esta funcao do ng-click e popularia os inputs dor form. ai que esta o problema não consigo popular os inputs do form.
Este controller nao enxerga o ng-model do form. Se eu utilizar o $rootScope tudo certo como vc disse.

Comment: Por uma questão de simplicidade, não sei se você deveria separar o seu controller em segmentos tão pequenos assim. Você poderia criar o controller do modal - modalCtrl e nele existir as funções referentes ao modal. Ex.: eu possuo um controller para carrinho de compras - cartCtrl, nele existe as funções: $scope.addItem, $scope.removeItem, $scope.clearCart e $scope.checkOut, onde a base de dados dele vem de um factory, como no exemplo da minha resposta. Não seria possível uma organização assim para você? precisa mesmo segmentar o controller?

Comment: você tem razão, acho que estou separando demais as coisas. Vou seguir sua orientação Celsom. Nota 10, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar =D

Answer (score 0):

Veja se esse exemplo te ajuda:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('igCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.pwd = "";
    
    $scope.algumaCoisaQualquer = "JEC não cai!!!! cvai e figay vão cair!!!";
    
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
    $scope.loggingIn = false;

    $scope.showLogin = function () {
        $scope.loggingIn = true;
    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
        // do your logout logic
        $scope.user = null;
        $scope.loggedIn = false;
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        // do your login logic
        $scope.loggingIn = false;
        $scope.loggedIn = true;
    };
});

app.directive('igLogin', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>' +
'  <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" + role = "dialog" aria-labelledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true" > ' +
'    <div class = "modal-dialog" > ' +
'      <form name = "form" ng - submit = "submit()" > ' +
'        <div class = "modal-content" > ' +
'          <div class = "modal-header" > ' +
'            <button type="button" class = "close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()" > Cancel </button>' +
'              <h3>{{algumaCoisaQualquer}} </h3 > ' +
'          </div>' +
'          <div class="modal-body">' +
'            <table border="0"><tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="email" ng-model="email"></input > </td></tr> ' +
'            <tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type = "password" ng-model = "pwd" > </input></td></tr>' +
'            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" ng-click="submit()" value="Login"></input ></td></tr></table> ' +
'          </div>' +
'        </div > ' +
'      </form>' +
'    </div > ' +
'  </div>' +
'</div > ',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            
            $scope.submit = function() {
                $scope.login();
          $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
            };
            
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $scope.loggingIn = false;
          $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
            };
            
            $scope.$watch('loggingIn', function() {
                if ($scope.loggingIn) {
              $("#loginModal").modal('show');
                };
           });   
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="igCtrl"> 
        <a href="#" ng-hide="loggedIn" ng-click="showLogin()">login</a>
        <a href="#" ng-show="loggedIn"ng-click="logout()">logout</a>
        <ig-login></ig-login>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar o seguinte, utilize o objeto que contem as informações que quer enviar para a modal como two way data binding, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
angular.module('app.directives')
.directive('formCall', function(appAngularConfig) {

    return {
        templateUrl: appAngularConfig.baseUrl + "/build/js/views/templates/__form_call.html",
        restrict: "E",
scope:{
seuObjecto: '='
}
    }

});

angular.module('app.directives')
.directive('formCall', function(appAngularConfig) {

    return {
        templateUrl: appAngularConfig.baseUrl + "/build/js/views/templates/__form_call.html",
        restrict: "E",
scope:{
seuObjecto: '='
}
    }

});
```

Comment: Mayllon Baumer, obrigado pela ajuda, mas não da. Porque estou com problema no ng-model do form carregado pela diretiva do template quando a modal se abre. So o controller que esta carregando a modal que funciona. Se eu chamar em outro controller, que é o que estou querendo ele não enxerga o ng-model do form.

Comment: Hmmm, veja se isso não resolve: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94871/passar-diretiva-dentro-de-template/94873?noredirect=1#comment192596_94873